# MongoDB with Mongoose: E11000 duplicate key error index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm (trying) to build an API system using mongoose, express and node. Right now I've two Schemas: user and event.

User Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  profileImage: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    'default': false
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
    'default': ''
  }
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Event Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = mongoose.model('User').schema;

var eventSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  },
  place: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  distance: {
    type: String,
    'default': '-1'
  },
  eventType: {
    type: Number,
    'default': 2 /* 0 = Asfalto, 1 = Trail, 2 = Otros */
  },
  attenders: [userSchema],
  comment: {
    type: String,
    'default': ''
  }
});

mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

And then I've defined a controller to manage POST requests over a certain endpoint. On my controller I only checks 'title' and 'place' fields on Event requests, like this:

```
if (!req.body.title) {
    response.sendJSON(res, 400, null, {"message": "title param is needed"});
    return;
  }

  if (!req.body.place) {
    response.sendJSON(res, 400, null, {"message": "place param is needed"});
    return;
  }

  Events
    .create({
      title: req.body.title,      
      place: req.body.place
    }, function(err, event) {
      if (err) {
        response.sendJSON(res, 400, null, err);
      } else {
        response.sendJSON(res, 201, event, null);
      }
    });
};
```

So I'm sending a request, using a 'title':'Example title', 'place':'Spain' as body params.

The first request creates new event successfully, but the nexts requests show me this error:

```
"status": 400,
    "error": {
        "code": 11000,
        "index": 0,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error index: som-passatge.events.$attenders.email_1 dup key: { : null }",
        "op": {
            "title": "Título de evento 22",
            "place": "Valencia",
            "_id": "56cc905d496141587dc47caf",
            "comment": "",
            "attenders": [],
            "eventType": 2,
            "distance": "-1",
            "date": "2016-02-23T17:01:17.650Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    },
    "response": null
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: "email" is marked as unique. If it's undefined, that is one instance of an email, so you can't have two of them that are undefined.

Comment: Well, but the userSchema is embedded, as far as my JS illiteracy allows me to see.

Comment: Try using a [sparse index](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-sparse) instead.

Comment: Moreover, don't put a "unique" index on the "attenders" array content at all. Likely you are trying to keep the content of the attenders array "unique" but "within the document". An index is the wrong approach to this as it persists across "all documents", and that means that no other "document" can contain the same entry within the array. There are other ways to keep unique entries in an array. Notably `$addToSet` or even testing for the element on update with `$push`. Those are what you use. Remove the index ( missing code definition ) with `db.events.dropIndex({ "attenders.email": 1 })`

Comment: You set 'email' unique property as true in the  userSchema and the userSchema referenced in eventSchema 'attenders'. I think this is why the duplication error showing.

Comment: Solved after removing "required: true" on the userSchema! I also need to drop the entrie db